# How do I turn k,v into a {k:v} ?

Tags: python

How do I turn k,v into a {k:v}, as short and pythonically as possible?

Comment: You have a variable `v` and a variable `k` and you want to make a `dict`? `{k: v}` is perfectly pythonic

Comment: @gnibbler -- comeon mate.  make it an answer or the wrong thing gets +1'd too many times!

Comment: @PhilCooper, ok i make it an answer

Answer (score 6):

You have a variable `v` and a variable `k` and you want to make a `dict`? `{k: v}` is perfectly pythonic

Answer (score 4):

You can convet a tuple to a dict. Try this:

```
>>> dict([('k', 'v')])
{'k': 'v'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming `k, v` here is a tuple that you have in some variable, which I will call `x`.  Here are a few options:

```
x = ('k', 'v')
d = dict([x])
```

or...

```
d = {x[0]: x[1]}
```